# Get all Target instances for a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

If I only register one method of one class to a delegate, I can use the `delegate.Target`, but when I subscripe more methods from different classes this does not work anymore. Is there another way to access the subscribers list of this delegate?

Here is the code: The foreach loop is being evaluated to null at runtime (it compiles)

```
    public delegate void WriteMessage(string msg);

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        var writer = new WriteMessage(myClass.WriteMessage);

        writer += SaySomething; //method in this class
        writer += myClass.SayShit; //instance class
        writer += AnotherClass.Say; //static class

        foreach(string target in (string[])writer.Target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(target);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void SaySomething(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HI!!!!");
    }
}
```

complete code:
http://pastebin.com/AzzRGMY9

Comment: Please show some minimal code, an explain in what way it "does not work".

Comment: Are you spinning this all into one delegate instance?

Comment: @Anon Yeah I think I am doing it that way!

Comment: Why would you expect the cast to `string[]` to work? Any why are you even using `string`? `writer.Target` is `null` because the last method is static, so it has no target. If it was something else, your cast would throw an exception.

Comment: @svick Thanks, I got the idea :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Delegate[] list = delegate.GetInvocationList();
```

That will get you an array of `Delegate` objects, which you can use to get the list of `Target`s.

Comment: This partly works, but I see 2 empty lines when doing `Console.WriteLine(target.Target);` in a foreach loop over `list` var.

Comment: @Sean87 `Target` is the *instance* on which the method is called. If the method is static, there is no instance, so `Target` is `null`.

Comment: OK, the first and third are bound to myClass, which is stored in the `Target`, but the second and fourth are bound to static methods, so `Target` is null (which translates to an empty string).

Comment: Thank you, @KendallFrey.  That comment solved a problem I was having, unrelated to the OP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is just additional information from the accepted answer, as I am looking the same information online.

If you want to invoke all registered methods upon receiving all the invocation list, you can use this code:

```
 Delegate[] listAllRegisteredMethods = writer.GetInvocationList(); //writer is the variable based on the question example

        foreach(Delegate c in listAllRegisteredMethods )
        {
            object[] p = { }; //Insert your parameters here inside the array if your delegate has parameters
            c.DynamicInvoke(p); //Invoke it, if you have return values, assign it on a different variable
        }
```